# display a salt minion's master server(s)

Tags: saltstack

I'm starting to play with Saltstack and I haven't found a way to display any runtime details of a salt minion. Specifically I wanted to display the salt master server(s) that a salt minion is currently utilizing.

It seems like there are several places that the salr master server details can be specified, including the `/etc/salt/minion` configuration file, configuration files located in `/etc/salt/minion.d/` and dynamically (which I admit, I don't really understand yet).

I didn't see anything in the man pages to show this kind of info.

This would be useful to help troubleshoot and "explore" inherited installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default grain with that information:

In a template or sls file:

```
{{ grains.master }}
```

From command line:

```
salt minion_id grains.item master
```

Comment: I suspect `<minion_id>` was meant.  I for one didn't have `salt` available, just `salt-call`.  There, the magic seemed to be `sudo salt-call grains.get master`, a command that Google has zero matches for, so surely I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/etc/salt/minion` first. If there isn't a master set explicitly there, salt minions default to trying to connect to salt, so check resolv.conf.